# Checking if an array contains any values from another array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects that is structured like so

```
const tools = [
   {name:"React", image:"react.svg"},
   {name:"Firebase", image:"firebase.svg"},
   {name:"CSS", image:"css.svg"},
]
```

I then have an array of strings.

```
const arr = ["React", "Firebase"]
```

How can I check that the 'tools' array includes all of the filters in the 'arr' array?

I think I am supposed to use the array.every() or the array.some() operator, but i am not sure how to implement either one in this case.

I found this function from a duplicate question, but it doesn't exactly fit my use case as the first array is an array of objects.

```
let checker = (arr, target) => target.every(v => arr.includes(v));
```

So my assumption is to loop through the 'tools' array and perform the check that way, but that doesn't seem right logic-wise?

If these were 2 straight up arrays of strings I could do a simple includes() operator and be done.

How do I move on from here? I'm considering pulling the individual name properties out of the array into a proxy array, so then it is two arrays of strings, but I feel like that is much less efficient than doing it with some() or every().

Edit: I am not sure I was clear, but I am checking against the 'name' property in the tools array.

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Set` from the target array, and then reduce the objects' array (`arr`) and remove each found item (`name` in this case) from the accumulator. If the `size` of the Set is `0`, then all targets were found in the array:

```js
const checker = (cb, arr, target) => !arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
  acc.delete(cb(o))
  
  return acc
}, new Set(target)).size

const tools = [{"name":"React","image":"react.svg"},{"name":"Firebase","image":"firebase.svg"},{"name":"CSS","image":"css.svg"}]

console.log(checker(o => o.name, tools, ["React", "Firebase"]))

console.log(checker(o => o.name, tools, ["React", "Firebase", "Cats"]))
```

With TS types ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBMAWBTYBrRAnGBeGAeAKgHwAUAUDHAEYBcMxItAhmAJ4CU2hM+ANDOTEbp0TVgG0AunwFQhAc0RRa+SaTa1KIEABtEzTjACEQ9ADp0iACYBXYImLFGwYLQDKigoT4NBrDli4AbwEnYFNLRF0oe2BKejY2AQELKGt0MEFnUgBfPjBEAHcYdyhiWXQFKATTCABLAC9EUlJQSFgoLW0IbBgxARhAsEYAW0RqACIAJT1gKHG+WuHGBQmLJygagDc5cdz+wZGx8YAxWotKRghEeZhF5aOAMzPEC6utnb2KAaHRiYBhVyuG53FbjYAQCDvXY8UgSZqtCA6RCmbQgOTEBDINDoegGECmH6IPgdHQQPhiKYzOZ8E7PV7XCQJeHgRG6FFojFIVAYXEBGD4wnEzpk3qU9Y3WnnS7XGl-RhQCDjRlsIA)):

```
const checker = <T>(
  cb: (o: any) => T, 
  arr: any[], 
  target: T[]
): boolean => !arr.reduce((acc: Set<T>, o: any) => {
  acc.delete(cb(o))
  
  return acc
}, new Set(target)).size
```

Comment: Your snippet has an error.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution to this is to use array.prototpye.some() method. It wilkl

```js
const tools = [
   {name:"React", image:"react.svg"},
   {name:"Firebase", image:"firebase.svg"},
   {name:"CSS", image:"css.svg"},
]

const arr = ["React", "Firebase"]

function findCommon(arr1, arr2){ 
 arr1.forEach(obj => {
   const key = Object.values(obj)
    console.log(key.some(item => arr2.includes(item)))
    }
  )
}

findCommon(tools, arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to use `.some()`:

```
const tools = [
  {name:"React", image:"react.svg"},
  {name:"Firebase", image:"firebase.svg"},
  {name:"CSS", image:"css.svg"},
];

const arr = ["React", "Firebase"]

const result = arr.every((item) => tools.some((tool) => tool.name === item));

console.log(result); // returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm considering pulling the individual name properties out of the array into a proxy array, so then it is two arrays of strings, but I feel like that is much less efficient than doing it with `some()` or `every()`.

It's by far the easiest approach.

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) over the tools array and get an array of names. Then check to see if the filter array contains all of them.

```js
const tools = [
  {name:'React', image:'react.svg'},
  {name:'Firebase', image:'firebase.svg'},
  {name:'CSS', image:'css.svg'}
];

const arr = ['React', 'Firebase'];
const arr2 = ['React', 'Firebase', 'Steve'];
const arr3 = ['React', 'Firebase', 'CSS'];
const arr4 = ['Firebase'];
const arr5 = ['Steve'];

function contains(tools, arr) {
  const names = tools.map(obj => obj.name);
  return arr.every(el => names.includes(el));
}

console.log(contains(tools, arr));
console.log(contains(tools, arr2));
console.log(contains(tools, arr3));
console.log(contains(tools, arr4));
console.log(contains(tools, arr5));
```